# Handling push notification interaction in foreground on android

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to handle foreground notification interaction on android but that doesn't work at all. I'm using following code which works well on ios foreground and both iOS/android background. Am I missing anything?

Code:

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage event) async {

        if (event.notification != null) {
          await navigatorKey.currentState!.pushNamed("/newRoute");
        }
      });
```

Comment: Android foreground is different. You need to create a high importance notification channel and use [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) to manage messages. See [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/notifications#foreground-notifications).

Comment: Thanks @PeterKoltai for sharing. I already have high importance channel, since notifications are coming while app in foreground. its the only thing I need to do - to handle clicks on them on android.

Comment: Do you use this [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) package? With this you can display the notification and handle click on Android / foreground.

Comment: @PeterKoltai Yes I do use it for displaying notifications on android. Will see what it takes to add click interaction